# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: java, json, exception, gson

This is my JSON data:

```
   [
        {
        "page": 0,
        "threads": [
            {
                "no": 498507562,
                "last_modified": 1375984181
            },
            {
                "no": 498503346,
                "last_modified": 1375984243
            },
            {
                "no": 498497523,
                "last_modified": 1375984241
            },
            {
                "no": 498496579,
                "last_modified": 1375984241
            },
            {
                "no": 498499114,
                "last_modified": 1375984240
            },
            {
                "no": 498503169,
                "last_modified": 1375984239
            },
            {
                "no": 498497038,
                "last_modified": 1375984239
            },
            {
                "no": 498501946,
                "last_modified": 1375984238
            },
            {
                "no": 498507181,
                "last_modified": 1375984237
            },
            {
                "no": 498505625,
                "last_modified": 1375984236
            },
            {
                "no": 498505578,
                "last_modified": 1375984242
            },
            {
                "no": 498507346,
                "last_modified": 1375984236
            },
            {
                "no": 498497504,
                "last_modified": 1375984236
            },
            {
                "no": 498486742,
                "last_modified": 1375984234
            },
            {
                "no": 498502590,
                "last_modified": 1375984232
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "page": 1,
        "threads": [
            {(...so on)
```

This is my code for deserialization:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONArray pageJson = JsonReader.readJsonArrayFromUrl(
    "https://api.4chan.org/b/threads.json");
System.out.println(pageJson.toString());

PageResponse PageResponse = gson.fromJson(pageJson.toString(), PageResponse.class);
```

I get the error on PageResponse. Here is my PageResponce class. I think I might be handling the information right. I've only worked with JsonObjects. I would like to know how to get "page": 0, and then how to get the "threads"

```
public class PageResponse {

List<Page> pages;

public List<Page> getPages() {
    return pages;
}
```

}

My Page class

public class Page {

```
int page;

public int getPage() {
    return page;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSONArray#getJSONObject()` to pull the `Page` object out of array first.

```
Page page = gson.fromJson(pageJson.getJSONObject(0).toString(), Page.class);
System.out.println(page.getPage()); // 0
```

To deserialize all the pages use

```
Page[] pages = gson.fromJson(pageJson.toString(), Page[].class);
System.out.println("Total: " + pages.length); // 2
System.out.println("pages[0] = " + pages[0].getPage()); // pages[0] = 0
```

Alternatively, add an extra set of `{}` to your JSON string to match against enclosing `PageResponse` object. Its `List<Page>` would now match against the `Page[]` objects that were shown deserialized above.

```
PageResponse pageResp = gson.fromJson("{ pages : " + pageJson.toString() + " }",
                                                              PageResponse.class);
System.out.println(pageResp.getPages().get(1).getPage()); // 1
```

Now, if you extend your `Page` class with `Threads` as well

```
class Page {
    private int page;
    private List<Threads> threads;

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public List<Threads> getThreads() {
        return threads;
    }
}

class Threads {
    private long no;
    private String last_modified;

    public long getNo() {
        return no;
    }

    public String getLastModified() {
        return last_modified;
    }
}
```

The whole JSON would deserialize successfully.

```
System.out.println(pageResp.getPages().get(0).getThreads().size()); // 15

System.out.println(pageResp.getPages().get(0)
                           .getThreads().get(0).getNo()); // 498507562
System.out.println(pageResp.getPages().get(0)
                           .getThreads().get(0).getLastModified()); // 1375984181
```

Comment: getJSONObject(0) would give you the first page object which would give 0 for a getPage() call.

Comment: I've figured it out! Thanks you so much.

Comment: @EmmanuelCortes Thanks for accepting. My use of `PageResponse[]` was incorrect though. I've tested and covered all the cases (including nested threads) now. Take a look if you like.

Comment: pages.length returns 16 instead of 2. I get a NullPointerException on every pageResp println() I run.

Comment: @EmmanuelCortes That's because I only replicated the first page as page:1 again (just changed its index). I don't have the complete JSON with me. My two pages are identical.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you don't have all of the JSON, but the just println(pageResp) itself give me a NullPointerException.

Comment: @EmmanuelCortes Works for me. Here's my [source code](http://pastebin.com/jkMTgL3w) and my [data.json](http://pastebin.com/eX5wYZ5k) file.

Comment: In your source Where you initialized pageResp you have " "{ pages :"  but on here you have "{ response :". Thanks for all your help!!!!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I missed updating. Fixed it for future reference.